# Robotic police patrolling a park

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I don't remember the title or author a story with a plot roughly as follows.

There is a park where people can do whatever they like except that it is monitored by floating robotic police (which are spherical?) which temporarily zap anyone who is doing something dangerous.

**Edit**:

Here is some *additional information* that can help in identifying the story in question. However, any other story with a similar theme would also be interesting. In other words, would be interested in stories with the "moral"

> A high surveillance society could also be a society which gives people more freedom.

Some guy disables all the robots simultaneously and chaos ensues.

One of the phrases that stuck in my mind was about a person who walks nude through the park until this happens. After that they are hiding because "there is a difference between nude and naked".

Comment: "Nude is artistic; naked is defenceless."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Cloak of Anarchy](https://larryniven.net/stories/cloak_of_anarchy.shtml), by Larry Niven.

Floating cop monitoring drones:

> Within King's Free Park was an orderly approximation of anarchy.
> People were searched at the entrances. There were no weapons inside.
> The copseyes, floating overhead and out of reach were the next best
> thing to no law at all.
>
> There was only one law to enforce. All acts of attempted violence
> carried the same penalty for attacker and victim. Let anyone raise his
> hand against his neighbor, and one of the golden basketballs would
> stun them both. They would wake separately, with copseyes watching. It
> was usually enough.

A guy in the park figures out a way to kill all the drones:

> She spotted me, yelled "Russell! Here!" in a voice that must have
> reached both ends of the park. In answer I lifted my arm semaphor
> style, slowly over my head and back down.
>
> And every copseye in King's Free Park fell out of the sky, dead.
>
> Jill looked about her at all the startled faces and all the golden
> bubbles resting in bushes and on the grass. She approached me somewhat
> uncertainly. She asked, "Did you do that?"
>
> I said, "Yah. If I wave my arms again they'll all go back up."

And naked folks:

> Nudity was popular in a Free Park. That night, nakedness was not.
> There must have been pieces of that cloak all over King's Free Park. I
> saw at least four that night: one worn as a kilt, two being used as
> crude sarongs, and one as a bandage.